# Bundling PostgreSQL in an app installer for Windows 7

Tags: postgresql, windows-7, windows-xp, cygwin, postgresql-9.2

I am working in a stand alone JAVA application using postgreSQL 7.4.2 as database. The application is not working in Windows 7. The postgreSQL server is run using cygwin. shell scripts are written to install the postgreSQL from source code, setup the server and create the database during application installation(currently the application runs on Windows XP)

We have decided to update to 9.4.2 version of postgreSQL. But in the manual it is written that "Running postgreSQL server using cygwin environment is not recommended".

My question is: If cygwin is not recommended then what is the alternate environment to install the postgreSQL from source code, setup the server and create the database during application installation on Windows 7.

I am a JAVA developer, not a database guy. But i was asked to do this migration. please help me in getting things right.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, your best bet is to bundle the .zip binaries of a pre-built PostgreSQL release. This gives you the same pre-tested binaries that're distributed in the installer and makes updating to a new point release as easy as stopping the server, replacing the binaries, and starting the server.

You can get pre-built binaries of stock PostgreSQL from [EnterpriseDB](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgbindownload).

If you insist on building from source, do so using the native Microsoft Visual C++ toolchain as documented in the PostgreSQL manual [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/install-windows.html). Getting the pre-requisite libraries is quite painful, so I wrote some tools that help with this; you can [find the pg_build_win tool here](https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/pg_build_win). I *strongly* recommend that you use the prebuilt binaries instead of building your own unless you have extremely compelling reasons; that tool is mostly intended for automated integration testing and development use.

Please don't use PostgreSQL on Cygwin. It's not well tested or well supported and it may go away in a future release if the couple of users who still care about it stop maintaining it. If for whatever reason you can't/won't use MSVC, you can use the gcc-based MinGW toolchain to build native Windows binaries.

If your program runs under Cygwin and hasn't been ported to run under native Windows yet (you should probably get onto that) you *can* safely compile and use `libpq` under Cygwin to connect to a native Windows PostgreSQL build.

(BTW, it's "Java" not "JAVA"; it isn't an acronym).

Comment: I have tried creating the database using script. I got the following error:

C:\Program Files\cygwin\bin\bash.exe (6096): *** couldn't allocate cygwin heap, Win32 error 0, base 0x690000, top 0x69E000, reserve_size 57344, allocsize 57344, page_const 4096
      1 [main] bash 888 sync_with_child: child 6096(0x1D8) died before initialization with status code 0x1
  21479 [main] bash 888 sync_with_child: *** child state waiting for longjmp
./install_database.sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable.

What does this indicate????

Comment: @user2416545 Since "with script" tells me absolutely nothing, I could not possibly guess. Maybe you should post a new question with all the appropriate details? Anyway, again, I *really* do not recommend using Cygwin for PostgreSQL and you are.

Comment: I will stop using cygwin. I have one doubt here: If I use pre-built binaries, will I be able to set up the server and database creation using the binaries(i.e. initdb, postgres, pg_dump) in .bat files. If this is possible then i believe cygwin is not needed.

Comment: @user2416545 Yes, of course. They take the same arguments etc, they just don't require running under Cygwin. You can even invoke them from a Cygwin shell if your application otherwise depends on Cygwin. The only limitation is that a Cygwin binary can't link to a native `libpq`; however, you can still use a cygwin `libpq` with a native Windows PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. My application is using cygwin to configure the server and to create the database during application installation. The application runs on native windows environment and does not require cygwin. So with your info, I will go ahead with the .bat files and remove cygwin from my application.

Comment: @user2416545 Yikes, yes, or use vbscript or python or ... practically anything but cygwin when you're just using it for an installer!